# float ads over mikrotik hotspot

Tags: wireless-networking, hotspot

i have recently installed mikrotik hotspot with my own WiFi portal for ads purpose and i am successful to preview ad on splash page(alogin.html) by injecting my ads script but is it possible to show float advertisement in every webpage which user visits?

Comment: While you might be able to do that did you think about the user experience?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this.

Major providers are moving to HTTPS to prevent this kind of behaviour - the information your router sees is encrypted - thus the large sites most people spend most time engaged in will lock this kind of behavior out.

And if you think about it, thats the way it should be - an end user should not trust the connection they go through, and thus people serving data will try and protect against the man in the middle.